# Where can I find the MySQL socket on Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t connect to local MySQL server through socket ‘/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock’](https://superuser.com/questions/102664/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock)

I know I have MySQL installed and running, but I don't know where to look to find the MySQL socket on Snow Leopard. Where is it located?

Comment: Please don't post multiple quesiton. Edit your existing quesiton with this information. They are both related to the same problem.

Comment: Yes they are related, but they are completely different questions. I would have been able to solve the first question on my own, had I known the location of the MySQL socket on Snow Leopard. I am voting to reopen this question so that it may help others who may be asking the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check /tmp/mysql.sock.